# Python typing: tuple[str] vs tuple[str, ...]

Tags: python, python-typing

What's the difference between `tuple[str, ...]` vs `tuple[str]`? (python typing)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

giving a tuple type with ellipsis means that number of elements in this tuple is not known, but type is known:

```py
x: tuple[str, ...] = ("hi",)          #VALID
x: tuple[str, ...] = ("hi", "world")  #ALSO VALID
```

not using ellipsis means a tuple with specific number of elements, e.g.:

```py
y: tuple[str] = ("hi", "world")  # Type Warning: Expected type 'Tuple[str]', got 'Tuple[str, str]' instead
```

This goes in contrast to notation of other collections, e.g. `list[str]` means list of any length with elements of type `str`.

Comment: The difference with other collections is probably because tuples are immutable.

Comment: yes that's why it kind of makes sense. Though I'm not sure that would generalize as a rule, e.g. `frozenset[str]` seems to accept multiple elements.